# Why am I getting An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Tags: c#

I am getting this error An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Core.dll when I try run the program. Its giving me suggestions like "Determine the object is null before calling the method" and "use the "new" keyword to to create an object instance".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
   protected static string userString { get; set; }

    public virtual void GetUserString()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter a string of letters: ");
       userString = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
   }

    class ProgramOrder : Program
    {
        public virtual void SetOrder()
        {
            bool moveOn = userString.All(Char.IsLetter);  //Error here

            base.GetUserString();

            if (moveOn == true)
            {
                char[] array = userString.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}", array[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You used characters that are not letters.");
                Console.WriteLine("Please use ONLY letters.");
                SetOrder();
            }

        }
    }

    class TestProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProgramOrder P1 = new ProgramOrder();

            P1.SetOrder();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is your full exception including stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First call `base.GetUserString` then check your letters:

```
base.GetUserString();
bool moveOn = userString.All(Char.IsLetter);
```

Comment: That seemed to do it! Thanks. I will Mark yours as solved in 11 minutes when it will let me!!

Answer (score 0):

Your Userstring is null at the Moment you're trying to access it.

You can seither check for null first, or assign a default-value like string.empty.